# unable to submit form by clicking input submit button on IE11

Tags: html, submit

I have following form and unable to submit by clicking submit button.

```
<form name="fEdit" class="inputform" id="my_form" method="post" action="test" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="mode" value="update" />                                                                                                                                             
<input type="hidden" name="tab" value="<?=$tab?>" />                                                                                                                                           
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="" /> 
<input type="submit" value="確定" onclick="return confirm('Do you want to save？');" />
</form>
```

Comment: i think the problem is `action="test"` ..what is the extension of test? like `test.php`

Comment: @ShadowFiend is right. You have to give the action to valid page.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Even I click on submit button, it dose not do anything like not going the page that is indicated in the action, namely test. Source code in the above itself looks like working okay. But, when it comes to my ubuntu environment, it dose not do anything.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why I can not post was that HTML  maxlength attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is `action="test"`

The `action=" "` attribute specifies where to send the form-data when a form is submitted

example ..

```
<form action="test.html/test.php" method="post/get">
```